# 'node: not found' when using the 'cross-env' package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, cross-env

I'm trying to make a coding challenge involving firebase and next.js. The challenge includes a pre-configured project with some dependencies, including cross-env.

I already installed all dependencies using 'yarn install' as instructed but when I try to run 'yarn dev' so it uses an specific script file, I run into the following issue:

```
yarn run v1.22.21
$ bash ./scripts/dev.sh
/mnt/d/codechallenge/node_modules/.bin/cross-env: 12: node: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The error that says 'node: not found' is the one that I don't understand. This is my setup and what I currently tried:

- I have node properly installed, version 21.6.2
- I already uninstalled and installed all dependencies.
- I installed the cross-env dependency as global using `npm install --global cross-env` and `sudo npm install --global cross-env`.
- This is the first time I've run into this issue.
- As reference, the line '12' that the error is referring to points to the following line of code in the dependency file: `node  "$basedir/../cross-env/src/bin/cross-env.js" "$@"`

Do you know what can be causing this problem?

I appreciate your help and time.